# Play sound in AVD

Tags: android

I am working on a project where I need to create some `Button`s, which when clicked will play some tones. This is the code I use

```
package com.entrainment.www;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button mButtonOne;
Button mButtonTwo;
MediaPlayer mp;
MediaPlayer mp1; 


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tone_1);
    mp1=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tone_2);

    mButtonOne = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mButtonTwo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mButtonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            mp.start();
        }
    }); 

    mButtonTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            mp1.start();
        }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I have got the AVD to run and it's all fine, but when I click on the button, nothing happens.

Comment: Why are you setting content twice..? setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Answer (score 0):

Because you are setting the content twice.

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

call will inflate your layout.

Whenever you set it for the second time new copy will be made, so

`mButtonOne` and `mButtonTwo` are the instances of first inflatted layout, but your curret view is second inflatted layout.
               To simply say buttons you are seeing in your screen are different because they belong to second layout. So you are clicking on button which don't have any actions set by you.

So remove  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` second time.

Comment: I can only see it once.What do you mean I have it twice?

Comment: DUUUUUUUDEEEE/. Thanks a lot. You are a lifesaver. It works :))

Comment: @user2235756 Don't forgot to mark this as answer by clicking on the right mark beside he answer..